# Code :soap:Server Message: Insufficient Postage in stamps.com Api integration

Tags: php, soap

when i want to sent "CreateIndicium" request, it always say "Insufficient Postage" in stamps.com Api

What is error mean "Insufficient Postage" ?
or Any parameter value change.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

i find solution for "Insufficient Postage", because i don't have balance in stamps.com, so when i request to stamps.com, it response  "Insufficient Postage".